# Hide all other div's using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hide

When I click a button, it will show a certain div id. I also want it to hide all other div id's. Can someone point me to a tutorial on how to do this using `jQuery`? My current code is given below:

```
$('#show_link_group').click(function() {
  $('#link_group').show();
});
```

After it shows my `#link_group`, I want it to hide all other div's.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm

Comment: you need to share more info about what other div's to be hidden

Comment: Do you have a sample of the structure of your HTML? Are all the DIVs siblings? Do they all have IDs?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest giving all off your div's a class name and use this to hide them.

```
<div class="alert" id="item-one"></div>
<div class="alert" id="item-two"></div>
<div class="alert" id="item-three"></div>
```

Then using jQuery

```
// Hide all divs with a class of alert then show the div with id of item-one
$('.alert').hide().filter('#item-one').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#show_link_group").click(function()
{
     $('div').hide();
     $('#'+$(this).attr('name')).show();   
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/LtqKq/204/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:not()`

e.g. `$("div:not(#idOfDivToBeShown)").hide();` or `$("div#idOfDivToBeShown").show();`

see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gaowei1972/Cf5g5/)

Answer (score 0):

This will hide *all* other DIVs on the page, but show the DIV with `id="link_group"`

```
$('#show_link_group').click(function() {
    $('div').hide();
    $('#link_group').show();
});
```

However, if you wish to hide only certain other DIVs, you can assign a class to those other DIVs and then hide all DIVs with that class. Here is an example:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ya3Q/1/)</kbd>

```
<div id="one"   class="hideable">This is div one</div>
<div id="two">DIV two - not of the HIDEABLE class</div>
<div id="three" class="hideable">This is div three</div>
<div id="link_group" class="hideable">This is div LINK_GROUP</div>
<div id="four"  class="hideable">This is div four</div>
<div id="five"  class="hideable">This is div five</div>

<input type="button" id="show_link_group" value="Hide the rest" />

$(function(){
    $('#show_link_group').click(function() {
        $('.hideable').hide();
        $('#link_group').show();
    });

});
```